# How do I control LSF to send an e-mail at the start/completion/abort of my job?

Tags: lsf

I see PBS has -m b|e|a options, but I did not see any equivalent in LSF -u options.  How do I control LSF to send an e-mail at the start/completion/abort of my job ?  If I just use '-u', does it send an e-mail only at the completion of the job ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have to use -B (when the job begins) and -N (when the job completes) at the same time with -u option ?

```
BSUB –B –N -u my_email@biglab.com
```